# $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] Doesn't Work With HTTP Url Work Only With HTTPS

Tags: php

When My Web Site Is `https://example.com` The Function Works Properly And When i Use `http://example.com` It Doesn't Work

Here My Code :

```
<?php

$adfly = "exey.io"; 

$flink = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$host = parse_url($flink);

if (isset($host['host']) && $host['host'] == $adfly) {
echo "True". '<br>';
} 
else {
echo "False" . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have a server rewrite that redirects non-HTTPS traffic to HTTPS?

Comment: @BenM , there is no rewrite that redirects

Comment: Are you sure you're been referred from another page? Because if you load the page directly in the address bar, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will not exist.

Comment: @ruleboy21 yes i'm sure

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is sent by your browser.

Comment: Could be due to a restrictive [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) set by the originating site. The value `no-referrer-when-downgrade` would suppress sending of the header, when the protocol changes from HTTPS on the originating site, to HTTP on the target site.